# Back to basics with DCOUNT

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Trying to work out where am messing up here:

```
Dim Count AS string
Count = DCount("F", "tbl_1", "C = '" & .Acc & "'")
```

The problem is with the criteria part of the count, Ive tested without the criteria and it works fine.

Anything jump out to anyone?

The error received:

> Data Type mismatch in criteria expression

** UPDATE **
I've since discovered this works fine, but id still like to know why my original method didn't work

```
count = DCount("F", "tbl_1", "C =" & .Acc)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `C`?

Comment: Data type C is integer

Comment: You should use single quotes only for strings and not for numeric data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd still like to know why my original method didn't work

In your original code, you were using:

```vb
DCount("F", "tbl_1", "C = '" & .Acc & "'")
```

You stated that the field `C` is of **integer** data type, and therefore I would assume that `.Acc` also returns an integer value.

Therefore, if `.Acc` were to return `1`, the criteria expression would be evaluated as :

```vb
DCount("F", "tbl_1", "C = '1'")
```

Which is the equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```sql
select count(F) from tbl_1 where C = '1'
```

Since the field `C` is of **integer** data type, and the `where` clause is being supplied with the **string** `'1'`, this will result in the error:

> Data Type mismatch in criteria expression.

---

In the revised code, the `DCount` expression would be evaluated as:

```vb
DCount("F", "tbl_1", "C = 1")
```

Which is the equivalent to a SQL statement such as:

```sql
select count(F) from tbl_1 where C = 1
```

Correctly supplying the field `C` within the `where` clause with an **integer** value.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, I should of know better. Doh!. Many thanks